# React exercise: two arrays rendered by two children and displayed next to each other (Matching indexes) in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, properties, parent-child

I have a parent component and two child components.

The main goal is two display 3 names under each other (no list needed, was just for the line break):

**Expected outcome (three full names under each other without list:**

- firstname1 lastname1
- firstname2 lastname2
- firstname3 lastname3

All first names are in one array **firstName = ["Charles", "Scott", "Peter"]** and all last names are in another array **lastName = ["Xavier", "Summers", "Parker"]**

They should be past to the children components **(Child1.js)** and **(Child2.js)** as props and rendered back to **App.js** in the before mentioned way.

My current code (below) displays first all 3 first names and then all 3 last names below each other. What do I need to change to make it that way?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Child1 from "./Child1.js"
import Child2 from "./Child2.js"

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const firstNames = ["Charles", "Scott", "Peter"];
    const lastNames = ["Xavier",  "Summers", "Parker"]
    return (
      <div>
        <Child1 firstNames={firstNames} /> <Child2 lastNames={lastNames} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Child1.js (firstNames)**

```
import React from "react";

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.firstNames.map((element, index) => (
          <h1 key={index}>{element}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Child1;
```

**Child2 (lastNames)**

```
import React from "react";

class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.lastNames.map((element, index) => (
          <h1 key={index}>{element}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Child2;
```

Comment: Is this simplified version of more complicated logic or? I'm not sure why you want to have separate components.

Comment: @zhuber not really. it's an exercise that should have 3 components. It doesn't really say those components need to be in separate files ... that was my own interpretation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to map inside the main component in order to iterate between the two arrays:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Child1 from "./Child1";
import Child2 from "./Child2";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const firstNames = ["Charles", "Scott", "Peter"];
    const lastNames = ["Xavier", "Summers", "Parker"];
    return (
      <div>
        {firstNames.map((el, i) => (
          <div key={i} style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            <Child1 firstNames={el} /> <Child2 lastNames={lastNames[i]} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and then for child1

```js
import React from "react";

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.firstNames}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Child1;
```

same for child2.
I run this on codeSandBox and its working for me.

Comment: that works @asma. Maybe a detail: how would I add a blank space in between the names?

Comment: Why would I map through the first array and simply access via index for the second?

Comment: You can insert a non-breaking space:  <Child1 firstNames={el}/>&nbsp;<Child2 lastNames={lastNames[i]} />

Comment: I could've used a for loop and iterate on both arrays with same index, or I could've mapped on the second array, you can use any of them, the result is the same. I guess i just did that out of laziness.

Comment: thx ... I really wonder how it looks if I map on both arrays. Quite important for my learning. Could you update please?